# How to change the data to * but only 50% of the word

Tags: sql, sql-server

newbie here.
Want to know is there any chance to changes the words on sql server to * but only 50% of the datas?
Example :
select name from biodata

**Result :**

```
1. Mountain
2. Grace
3. Yellow
```

**Expected result** is

```
1. Moun****
2. Gr***
3. Yel***
```

Thabk you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! 
Below link may help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
select concat (
               substring(Name, 1, LEN(Name)/2),
               replicate('*', LEN(Name)/2)
              ) 
from biodata
```

--> `substring(Name, 1, LEN(Name)/2)` will get first half of the name

--> `replicate('*', LEN(Name)/2)` will repeat `*` for the remaining half of the name

--> And finally, `Concat()` will join both the strings.

Comment: Yes this is what i'm searching for. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want, preserving the length of the word as well:

```
select word,
       left(left(word, len(word) / 2.0) + replicate('*', len(word)), len(word))
from (values ('Mountain'), ('Grace'), ('Yellow')) v(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `len()`, `stuff()` and `replicate()` can get you there.

Use `len()` to get the length of the word.  Use `replicate()` to create a string of asterisks of the needed length, and use `stuff()` to overwrite the end of the word with asterisks. You could also use `left()` and concatenation instead of `stuff()`.

For example:

```
declare @string varchar(10) = 'abcdefghij'
select len(@string) -- returns 10
select left(@string, len(@string) / 2) -- returns 'abcde'
select replicate('*', len(@string) / 2) -- returns '*****'
select left(@string, len(@string) / 2) + replicate('*', len(@string) / 2) -- returns 'abcde*****'
```

I will leave it to you to decide how you want to handle strings with an odd number of characters, and how to organise the code neatly to work with a whole column rather than a single varaible. Note that the `len()` function is used repeatedly, so you can factor this out, for example, using `cross apply`.